# Keep getting this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FILE'. Any insight?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

We're using Spring Webflow(structure) and Hibernate for the data transfer.

Comment: Could you post the full error stack trace please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default annotation implementation for a table column, it will cause JDBCException…

@Column(name = "FILE",)

Solution
1. Enclose the keyword with square brackets [].
@Column(name = "[FILE]")

2. Use double quotes (“) to enclose it.
   @Column(name = "\"FILE\"")

Answer (score 1):

Could be that FILE is a keyword and can not be used without quotation ([] for SQLServer, "" for PG, etc).
In Hibernate quotation is done using `` around @Column's name property.

```
@Column(name="`FILE`")
```

Comment: Hi!
I've put ur suggestion into work,but it still doesnt work .

Comment: Did you notice differences in sql statement after quotation (eg. this_.[FILE] as FILE7_0_0_...)?

Comment: yep i notice their difference.hehe.Now it works!
thanks a lot man :)